# PCL equivalent of Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable?

Tags: c#, environment-variables, portable-class-library

Is there a Portable Class Library equivalent of Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable? If not, is there some way to detect if I'm on an environment that supports it and only call it in that scenario? I'm using profile 111.

Comment: No, it is only available on the desktop version of the .NET Framework.  Perhaps somewhat obvious, somebody with a phone or a slate isn't going to hack environmental variables to keep you happy.  Strongly avoid using an oracle to provide you with config information, just expose whatever you want to know as a property that the host app can assign.  It can decide how to implement configuration.  Using, say, an xml file or an Options dialog.

Comment: Configuration management is an application level concern, so libraries rarely need to access the environment. So I agree with Hans that you should pass the configuration to the code in the library.